# how to quickly inform the meteor client of a new document

Tags: meteor, publish, latency

Now with publish subscribe about 10 seconds transpire before
a new record is found on the client.

What can be done if just one record is published, yet not immediately
showing on the client ?

Comment: In my app pub-sub updates are virtually instantaneous (100-200ms in production, not local). You need to understand why your publication is so slow and/or what else your client might be doing that is interfering with showing new data. Using Kadira can be a big help to diagnose slow publications.

Comment: The 10 second delay hints that your app is using poll-and-diff and not oplog tailing for your publication. Make sure that you have oplog access (if you have deployed your app) and are sorting your query results, as failing to do so will prevent you from using it.

Comment: maybe since the 'update' is not from meteor, from another non meteor app the response is slow ?

Comment: pollingIntervalMs Number
(Server only) How often to poll this query when observing on the server. In milliseconds. Defaults to 10 seconds.
--> simply change to 1 second

Comment: I would not advise this, as poll-and-diff can be quite expensive. You should learn more about the way publications work and what type of optimizations you can perform.

Comment: As the new document is not coming from meteor, there is way for meteor to find out other than checking via the pollingInterval.

Comment: a simple 'event' service would suffice 'meteor-events' could quickly inform the client that the server is ready with data, it is meteor add meteor-events